# Odoo Internal Server Error while installing on amazon web server EC2

Tags: odoo-8

I am installing odoo8 on amazon EC2 web server . I installed ubuntu 14.04 on it and after that Odoo8 where executing all the steps it gives Internal Server Error for the Database Connection.

The error is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 290, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1290, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1264, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1406, in dispatch
    self.setup_db(httprequest)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1348, in setup_db
    httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1478, in db_monodb
    dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1452, in db_list
    dbs = dispatch_rpc("db", "list", [force])
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 115, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/service/db.py", line 73, in dispatch
    return fn(*params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/service/db.py", line 313, in exp_list
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 575, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 181, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 464, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 526, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: FATAL: role "ubuntu" does not exist
2015-07-01 11:41:16,580 1315 ERROR None openerp.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
```

Comment: I suggest posting your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the postgres user. Check the `db_user` in the `/etc/openerp-server.conf file`. Its looks like the user is `ubuntu` which is not a postgres user. You need to create the user `ubuntu` in postgres or change the user in the config file to an existing postgres user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is user name **ubuntu** is not exists in your postgres database,
Let's move to solution:

1. First, You need to create use that has name **ubuntu** in your postgres using below command

> CREATE USER ubuntu WITH PASSWORD 'ubuntu';

2. Then you need to give privilege to **ubuntu** user like this

> ALTER USER ubuntu CREATEUSER CREATEDB;